# Convert jquery click function into angularJS directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-selectors, accessibility

For a 'skip to content' accessibility link, this jquery in a controller works well:

```
  $scope.skipLink = $( document ).ready(function() {
     $(".skip").click(function(event){
       var skipTo="#"+this.href.split('#')[1];
     $(skipTo).attr('tabindex', -1).on('blur focusout', function () { 
       $(this).removeAttr('tabindex'); 
       }).focus();
     });
   });
```

Where the HTML is

```
    <a href="#content" class="skip sr-only sr-only-focusable">Skip to content</a>
```

Is there a way to rewrite this into a directive without using jquery?

Comment: This can certainly be re-written to be much more angular-friendly, but I am not sure why you would want to do this without jQuery. This would be a rather clunky solution without it.

Comment: @mhodges I agree, I was asked to make this more angular-friendly and I haven't had much luck. jqLite might be OK.  Would it not be a good idea to at least make this a directive instead of a scope within a controller?

Comment: Yes, I can post an answer with an example of how you can clean this up a little bit. I have to ask, do you have multiple "Skip to content" links and multiple content sections that can be skipped to?

Comment: @mhodges not at the moment. I don't think there will be, but we might have to use it again if they end up creating an alternate header view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, I don't think this should be done without jQuery. In order to make it more angular-friendly however, see [THIS DEMO](http://jsbin.com/mohamakuji/2/edit?html,js,output).

The idea is to leverage the click handler directives from angular and let jQuery do its work inside of your controller.

## AngularJS Controller

```
  $scope.skipToContent = function () {
    $("#content").attr('tabindex', -1);
  };
  $scope.removeTabIndex = function () {
    $("#content").removeAttr('tabindex'); 
  };
```

## HTML

```
<a href="#content" 
   ng-click="skipToContent()"
   class="skip sr-only sr-only-focusable">Skip to content</a>
<input id="content" 
       ng-blur="removeTabIndex()"
       style="display: block; margin-top:100vh;"/>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity, is there a reason this should be a controller instead of a directive? (i'm new to angularjs, if you couldn't tell)

Comment: @gallagher Not really, other than the fact that it is an isolated case, so building out a custom directive for a single use is a bit overkill. And you ARE using directives, FYI, that's what ng-* attributes are. They are just predefined, built-in, directives from the angular library.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use no javascript at all by setting the attribute `tabindex` on your content div.

```
<a href="#content" class="skip">Skip to content</a>

<div id="content" tabindex="-1" onclick="return false">
   This is my content
</div>
```

Note that the "skip to content" link should not be hidden for all users as it can be used by people with non visual disabilities (keyboard users, parkinson diseases, ...).